# execute a powershell script (hello world)

Tags: scripts, programming, webserver, microsoft, powershell

A `powershell` "hello world" script is spawning and bogging down the system:

```
Tasks: 413 total,   2 running, 411 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 42.8 us,  5.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 51.2 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8126688 total,  1785632 free,  4862820 used,  1478236 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8343036 total,  8343036 free,        0 used.  2875400 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
11915 thufir    20   0 3199524  76936  54220 S  19.2  0.9   0:00.58 b.sh        
11858 thufir    20   0 3068456  76988  54276 S  18.9  0.9   0:00.57 b.sh        
11820 thufir    20   0 3199516  77008  54292 S  18.5  0.9   0:00.56 b.sh        
11877 thufir    20   0 3330588  76796  54040 S  18.2  0.9   0:00.55 b.sh        
11896 thufir    20   0 3199532  76984  54232 S  18.2  0.9   0:00.55 b.sh        
11839 thufir    20   0 3199524  76808  54036 S  17.9  0.9   0:00.54 b.sh        
11934 thufir    20   0 3199520  77152  54360 S  17.9  0.9   0:00.54 b.sh        
10265 thufir    20   0 3609528 167556  83332 S   6.3  2.1   0:06.27 gnome-shell 
10002 thufir    20   0 3447780  86904  61024 S   4.6  1.1   0:00.72 b.sh        
 9965 thufir    20   0 3447764  86904  61036 S   4.3  1.1   0:00.69 b.sh        
 9982 thufir    20   0 3316688  86380  60528 S   4.3  1.1   0:00.71 b.sh        
10021 thufir    20   0 3447760  86548  60628 S   4.3  1.1   0:00.70 b.sh        
10040 thufir    20   0 3316696  86316  60524 S   4.0  1.1   0:00.71 b.sh        
10060 thufir    20   0 3316692  86680  60860 S   4.0  1.1   0:00.68 b.sh        
10080 thufir    20   0 3447768  85824  60020 S   3.3  1.1   0:00.66 b.sh        
 9948 thufir    20   0 3447768  86788  60792 S   3.0  1.1   0:00.66 b.sh        
11799 thufir    20   0 3068444  77012  54192 S   1.7  0.9   0:00.56 b.sh
```

the script:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat powershell/weather/b.sh 
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command


echo "hello world"
"done"


thufir@dur:~$
```

is it not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486441/262852) to make it an executable script?  Perhaps that's not the correct first line?

details for `powershell`:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion                                                                              

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleas BuildLabel 
                     eLabel               
-----  -----  -----  --------- ---------- 
6      0      1                           


PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> get-host                                                                                               


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 6.0.1
InstanceId       : 38ca179a-1605-49d3-8af2-15985d6c0536
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-CA
CurrentUICulture : en-CA
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace



PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> $PSVersionTable                                                                                        

Name                           Value                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                   
PSVersion                      6.0.1                                                                                   
PSEdition                      Core                                                                                    
GitCommitId                    v6.0.1                                                                                  
OS                             Linux 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018                     
Platform                       Unix                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                     


PS /home/thufir>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whoops:

```
$ 
$ cat powershell/weather/c.ps1 
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command


echo "hello world"
"done"


$ ./powershell/weather/c.ps1 
hello world
done
$
```

It just has to have `.ps1` file extension.  Microsoft.